# how could we access the properties of a control from variable holding control id in asp.net back end file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

**My def.aspx.cs file code ::**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (homecntpop.lattopics[i] != 0)
    {
        OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection("provider=sqloledb; data source=.\\sqlexpress; database=investment; integrated security=SSPI");
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from articleinfo where ArticleId=?", cn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("1", homecntpop.lattopics[i]);
        cn.Open();
        OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dr.Read();
        artdet1.Style.Add("width", "100%");
        cntlink1.InnerText = dr.GetValue(1).ToString();

        cn.Close();
    }
}
```

**My def.appx file code ::**

```html
<div class="cntdivo">
    <div id="arttopic1" class="arttopic" runat="server"><a id="cntlink1" href="bitcoins-how-it-gained-popularity-and-what-next.aspx" runat="server">Bitcoins : How it managed to gain such widespread popularity and what next?</a></div>
    <div id="artdescrb1" class="artdescrb" runat="server">Scope and future</div>
    <div id="artdet1" class="artdet" runat="server">
        <div style="float:left; margin-right:5px"> Author</div>
        <div id="artauthor1" class="artauthor" runat="server"></div> 
        <div style="float:left; margin-right:5px">Date</div> 
        <div id="artdate1" class="artdate" runat="server"></div>
        <div style="float:left; margin-right:5px"> Hits</div>
        <div id="arthits1" class="arthits" runat="server"></div>
        <div style="float:left; margin-right:5px"> Likes</div>
        <div id="artlikes1" class="artlikes" runat="server"></div>
        <div style="float:left; margin-right:5px"> Dislikes</div>
        <div id="artdislikes1" class="artdislikes" runat="server"></div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

now how could I access more such controls from def.aspx.cs file so that i could dynamically make changes to its properties.

Comment: Not sure what you're really after. All html tags with an `id` and `runat="server"` should be accessible from code-behind (your def.aspx.cs) in the same manner that you are using `cntlink1`. Also, as an aside, you should have your database objects (`OleDbConnection`, `OleDbCommand`, and `OleDbDataReader`) within [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) blocks.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for FindControl method, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw(v=vs.110).aspx